# How to hide button when in edit mode in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

Can i hide my button inside cell when edit mode? My cell populate by array, save in plist. This is my code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [titleArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"the indexpath.row = %i",indexPath.row);

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];

    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(250.0, 25.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
    [button setTitle:@"!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setTag:indexPath.row + 100];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onoffBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // my label code

    UIImageView *bgCell = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0 , 320, 80)];
    bgCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BG.jpeg"];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    // other cell contentView addSubview everything

    return cell;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

This is my edit button

```
- (IBAction)editBtn:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *editBtn = (UIButton *)sender;
    editBtn.selected = !editBtn.selected;

    if (editBtn.selected)
    {
        button.hidden = YES;
        [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        button.hidden = NO;
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

with above code, my button hide in last cell only, just say if i have 3 cells. How do i hide all button hide when in edit mode? i want all button is hiding. Below is my onoffBtn.

```
- (IBAction)onoffBtn:(id)sender
{
    tempIndexPath = [_tableView  indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview]];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:tempIndexPath];
    UIButton *onoffBtn = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:tempIndexPath.row+100];

    onoffBtn.selected = !onoffBtn.selected;
    if (onoffBtn.selected)
    {
        // start
    }
    else
    {
        // stop
    }
}
```

Please teach me more. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to call this method for all the UiTableViewCells of the table:

```
 if (editBtn.selected)
        {

for (int row = 0, rowCount = [_iTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; row < rowCount; ++row) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [_iTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0]];

      UIButton *onoffBtn = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:tempIndexPath.row+100];
     onoffBtn.hidden=YES;
    }
   }
```

Comment: im sorry, im beginner, i dont really understand where is rowCount and section comes from? but at least i have tried using your method but it still cant hide my onoffBtn.

Comment: rowCount is the total no. of rows in the section:0 {that is rowCount = [_iTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];}of the tableView as your tableView has only one section.You can write it before For loop also.

Comment: hey, whoever you are, thank you for teaching me. it only hide for first cell only but i think i can fix it using your method. at least i  understand. thank you again.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper I have use same Solution still I am there on that Problem . I do have same issue ...

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper can U check this Updated Question . I have edit in this Questions ..

Comment: I am sorry i am not able to get the edit..please come to any chat room like : iOS developers, etc.  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15038/ios-developer-family

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper this is my Question Link . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087434/hide-uibutton-of-uitableviewcell